# Zentyal: "incorrect password" on login

Tags: permissions, users, groups, zentyal

I've installed Zentyal 3.3 on my virtual Ubuntu server (12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-23-generic x86_64)) [as package](http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Community/Installation/InstallationGuide#Zentyal3.3packages). But when I try to login, Zentyal throws "Incorrect password". I've added my user to the `sudo` and `adm` group, but I can't login into the Zentyal web interface.

Connection over SSH with this user works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do?:

> sudo add user root sudo

root must be added to the sudo group, that is of course if root is your login name as administrator

Comment: YES ! works like a charm!
one thing, should be sudo adduser root sudo and it's really working now, I can log with root OS credentials, thanks !